# Hibernate Sequence Generation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I updated to Spring Boot 3 and now my sequence generation does not longer work. I use an abstract entity class for the primary key of all my tables/entities. Currently I have a table named mytable1_seq with a column "next_val" for the entity mytable1 and a separate table mytable2_seq for the entity mytable2.

The CustomSequenceStyleGenerator only defines the sequence name.

Now it always tries to create a "real sequence" statement:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: (conn=580) 'xxx.mytable1_seq' is not a SEQUENCE
```

The parameter CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY is not longer available since spring boot 3. Is that the reason?

It is "not" possible to change the complete sequence handling, because it is a productive system. Is there a way to get the same behaviour as before?

```
    @Id
@GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "xx.xx.xx.CustomSequenceStyleGenerator",
        parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.CONFIG_PREFER_SEQUENCE_PER_ENTITY, value = "true"),
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INITIAL_PARAM, value = "1"),
        @Parameter(name = SequenceStyleGenerator.INCREMENT_PARAM, value = "1") 
})
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "generator")
private long id;
```

Comment: Hibernate 6 provides the sequence generation using database tables. Even more advanced then in 5. Please check TableGenerator class https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/id/enhanced/TableGenerator.html

Comment: I found this way already, but I'm not sure how to change this in a way that it works for a abstract entity. I do not want to add the annotation for each entity.

Comment: I tried a lot but unfortunately I was not able to manage it. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: I give up... Anything I have tried was not successful :( Maybe someone has an idea.

Comment: @Mar-Z Do you have an example how to use the database tables? :)